# Sitecore custom personalization rule not appearing in Custom Rule Editor

Tags: personalization, marketing-control-panel

I am facing a weird issue. Our custom personalization rules are not appearing in the `Rule Set Editor` window. These are not new rules and they used to appear all the time. All the already applied rules are still there. I even tried to create new rules but same issue, it also does not appear.

I am using `Sitecore 9 update 2`

All the rules are created using the method described in this link
[How to Customize Personalization Rules in Sitecore 8](https://www.sundoginteractive.com/blog/personalization-rules-in-sitecore-8)

Comment: Just for clarity on the question, it would be good to specify which version of Sitecore you are using. In most cases, it probably doesn't matter, but in some versions the items are in different locations.

Comment: I am using Sitecore 9 update 2 @JayS

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Personalization rules are under attached to the rule "Conditional Renderings". Here is the path to follow looking for your missing rule.

### Tags

A tag is the glue between rules and elements. You will have a custom tag under the item, `/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Definitions/Tags/`. Lets say that are called `Membership Status`. i.e `/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Definitions/Tags/Membership Status`

### Element

Under the item path `/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Definitions/Elements` you should have a Element where you custom rules exist. You will create a new element called `Membership Status`. In that Element there is a `Tags` item and a child called `Default`. Path would be `/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Definitions/Elements/Membership Status/Tags/Default`. In the Tag multilist, in the custom tag, you select the Tag you created in step 1 above.

### Condition Renderings

Finally you will have a custom Tag under the item `/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Conditional Renderings/Tags`. I usually name the tag custom. In the multilist, in the custom tag, you select the Tag you created in step 1 above.

Your rules in your Element Membership Status and tied to the rule Condition Renderings via the Tag Membership Status.

Comment: Damn! I forgot the conditional `/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Conditional Renderings/Tags` path. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure you've not accidently disabled Xdb locally by setting `<setting name="Xdb.Enabled">false</setting>` like I did and forgot about it as this didn't show up my custom rules for me.